# Android How Resume Listview after make a phone call

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, resume

I have a listview, in each item, i have a call button which can make a phone call with the telephone number in this item. After my phone call ended, how can I resume the previous listview (with the same position same view)?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should start a CallListener Service to monitor current call status. And also at your onPause() method you should save your current state with a pref or just you can save it to a .txt file. And when the call is over, put a method in your CallListener Class so that it can restart your service.

Comment: Do you think it takes too much time? for example i have a list view with 500 items and each item i have plurials infos. I don't know if we have something like save the context current and then restore it after the call end?

Comment: look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998137/android-preferences-saving-in-activity-or-preferenceactivity) this and [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState) this. This may answer your question..

Comment: also follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044508/how-to-save-and-retrieve-listitems-in-android)